# How to get the replace string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

```
const string = 'Hey My name is +++Vijay+++.';

console.log(string.replace(/\++(.*)\++/, 'A'));
```

As you saw in the above example I'm replacing `Vijay` with `A`, how can I get the `Vijay` in the place of `A`?
Like the replaced word should appear in `A`.

Comment: You need to store the replaced word and then replace it with A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use '$&' , which represents the matched string.

e.g.

```
console.log(string.replace(/\++(.*)\++/, '$&'));
```

Will get you the same exact result (since you're replacing Vijay with Vijay).

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: The Vijay word can be vary. It can be any name, but i want to that particular word because i need to add a editor for that word.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing it, you could extract them first then do the normal string replacement via loop without regex.

```
const string = 'Hey My name is +++Vijay+++.';
const regex = /\++(.*?)\++/g
const array = [...string.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(array);
```